# Removing specific anchor link from div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an anchor link that is generated and applied to all listings on the page. I need to only have it applied to one type of listing(STORY), and remove it from the others. I am using the following to style and label specific divs:

```
$(".list-unstyled li:contains('TEASER')")
      .parents('.col-xs-6')
      .find('.well-sm')
      .css("background", "#fdfd96")
      .append('<div class="badge type">TEASER</div>');
  $("dd:contains('STORY')")
      .parents('.col-xs-6')
      .find('.well-sm')
      .css("background", "#ffb347")
      .append('<div class="badge type">STORY</div>');
  $(".panel-body dd:contains('AD')")
      .parents('.col-xs-6')
      .find('.well-sm')
      .css("background", "#82CA9D")
      .append('<div class="badge type">AD</div>');
  $(".panel-body dd:contains('BUFFER')")
      .parents('.col-xs-6')
      .find('.lead')
      .css("background", "#f5f5f5")
      .append('<div class="badge type">BUFFER</div>');
```

I need to be able to apply the following anchor link to ONLY div's that contain 'STORY':

```
<a href="http://www.url.com/{{entityProps.uuid}}" id="share">Share Link</a>
```

I've tried something like

`.remove("#share")`

chained to the end of all but STORY, but this doesn't work.

Comment: You're using the `.remove()` method in the wrong way. I mean, your selector is invalid.

Comment: `.remove('#share')` would work, as you have the link ID.

Comment: But I don't think it would work just by chaining it to the end, as you moved your selector to the `parent` element.

Comment: Nope. Another way might be to find the "Share Link" text, and just hide that. Trying to figure out the best way to do that. I already have the functionality to do so, but I've tried appending the remove to it, with no luck.

Comment: I don't get you. If you have any unique information about the element, you can use it as a selector and just call the `.remove()`. The only wrong thing here is that your selector is invalid.

Comment: Unless you have more than a single element sharing the same `ID` in the page, which is invalid markup.

Comment: The markup is fine. I just need to be able to find the anchor tag with `id="share"`, and apply the remove() functionality to it. I'm updating my question with more detail.

Comment: Question has been updated with more detailed code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to be appending `.find('#share').remove()` to the end of the `.append()` of each of the listings I don't want the share button on.